# compile and execution compatibility in docker and host os

Tags: docker, compilation, x86-64, compatibility, arm64

Q1: I have a develop and production env as following:

develop env: host machine CPU: x86-64, host-os: CentOS 7.6, docker container os: Ubuntu 18.04. 
production env: production machine CPU: x86-64, host-os: Ubuntu 18.04.

I am wondering if I compile a program(depends on libraries like boost and drivers like CUDA, USB) inside the container, and transport the compiled binary to production env(with all required libraries and device drivers installed), is it possible execute the binary directly without recompile? or is there any risk of doing such things?

Q2: if the develop env changes to:

production env: production machine CPU: arm64, host-os: Ubuntu 18.04.

Is there any way that I can still do all compile work inside a container(like a arm64-simulator env) and run the binary on the production env directly?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to Q1:Yes you can. If you compile your code inside a docker container you would need to install lots of unnecessary libraries for compiling the code and you would end up having a large image.
I usually build a docker image just to run the compiled code and then copy my binary file into it.
You might want to create a base image and then build your services using that base image, in this way all of the services in your server would share the base image and you can save more space.

Answer to Q2:You can use docker multiple architectures support.
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/multi-arch/

In this way, you can build the image for all of the cpu architectures you need.
However, you might need to have a more complicated Dockerfile to check the architecture and change the building commands to compile your code (or copy the right compline binary for the target architecture) correctly for each architecture.